# How to setup shared folder in Virtual Box with Windows 10 as host and Centos guest

Tags: virtualbox, centos

I added my Documents folder as a shared folder when I created the Centos Virtual Box image with the following settings:

```
Folder path: C:\...(omitted on purpose ) 
Name: Documents(Windows) 
automount checked MountPoint Windows
```

I got the error:

> This location could not be displayed you don't have permission necessary to view "sf_Documents(Windows)".
>   After searching a bit online I realized that I need to create a sharedfolder usergroup and add my username to it, but I messed it up and I believe it is the name of the folder I used. Can I get some help on the exact commands to make this work on Centos please? I am working on learning Centos more. Here are the commands I put in:

```
mkdir -p /WindowsShared
groupad SharedUsers
groupadd SharedUsers
chgrp -R SharedUsers /WindowsShared
chgrp -R 2775 /WindowsShared
```

I tried to add the following,but I think I get error messages saying the folder does not exist even though I am looking at the folder and even I went inside it:

```
useradd -D -g SharedFolder sansari
useradd -D -g WindowsShared sansari
useradd -D -g /WindowsShared sansari
useradd -D -g WindowsShared sansari
```

I tried to follow [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-shared-directory-for-all-users-in-linux) link, but I believe I should have used a different folder name. I used Windows,but I should have used Documents(Windows). Can I get some help on cleaning this up and set it up right please?

Comment: Did you install VB Extensions (the equivalent of. VMware Tools) to facilitate file sharing?

Comment: @John- yes I did. Sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Try this tutorial on VB file sharing. It is for Ubuntu but the concepts should work.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-teQnZ8LEY.  It is a bit different than the link you pointed to above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Debian and Ubuntu the linux group for virtual box is named vboxsf. Check your centos group names and see if you see vboxsf. If so add your user to this group after running the extensions pak. You will need to restart linux after adding user to group.